# Are questions whose answers would determine if a work could be categorized as sci-fi considered on-topic?

Tags: discussion, scope

A [question about the show *Dexter*](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/8232/is-the-ghost-of-harrison-morgan-real) has been asked that essentially questions whether there is a sci-fi/fantasy element to a show generally regarded as "regular" fiction.

Is this appropriate for this site?  If the answer to the *Dexter* question is "no", then the show is clearly not on topic for our site, and should be closed.  However, we should be able to determine if the question itself is on-topic, without relying upon the answer for the decision.

Comment: One thing that complicates *Dexter* is that the book series—but not the TV series (yet?)—gets way into the fantasy territory starting with *[Dexter in the Dark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dexter_in_the_Dark)*.

Answer (score 8):

I believe that the question is off topic.

Genre is generally pretty obvious, and having one single aspect of a work that can create suspicion of the work actually belonging to the sci-fi/fantasy genre when it is generally categorized otherwise is insufficent.

That being said, it is not outside the realm of possibility for such a work to have a late reveal that changes the genre.

*Dexter* could show a new episode that makes quite clear that the "ghost" of Harry Morgan is, in fact, a manifestation of the spirit of Dexter's father, and not simply a device to represent some aspect of Dexter's internal thought processes.  If that were to happen, then questions about *Dexter* would be on-topic, but not *until* that canon episode making the transition was revealed.

Comment: They are very much off topic, see http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/350/what-questions-are-on-topic-and-what-questions-are-off-topic

Comment: Are you referring to "questions on genre classification"?

Comment: Yes, I should have stated as much... Sigh.

Answer (score 4):

I believe it is off-topic on Sci-Fi SE, but perhaps it's on-topic on META site?

Comment: This is my preferred answer. The meta site is okay to ask if it is on topic, but we've previously said these questions are off topic.

Answer (score 2):

As the asker of the questionable question, my opinion is of course that the question is on topic; as determining wether or not a given series is relevant to the site or not must be possible to determine within the framework of the site itself, but of course, I do realize there's a conflict of interest here.

Comment: We've always considered sf-nal elements of non-sf works on-topic, as well as non-sf elements of sf works (for a reasonable definition of sf). I think [this](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/337/spy-movies-books-on-topic) is the relevant discussion. So the answer to the larger question is yes.

Comment: Duly noted, and edit removed.

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for linking that discussion.  Based on item 5 of your answer, this seems pretty clearly on-topic.