# what constitutes an off-topic question?

Tags: support, scope

I had asked if a TV series could be considered sci-fi, and it was closed for being off-topic. Is asking if something meets the criteria of sci-fi off-topic when it comes to sci-fi?

Comment: Questions about whether or not something is/isn't on topic should be asked on meta, not the main site.

Comment: My phone says this is http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/4705/what-constitutes-an-off-topic-questions?noredirect=1#comment12585_4705

Comment: Isn't this meta?

Comment: Yes, this is meta - but your question about whether or not American Dad was sci-fi was on the main site.

Comment: Also, http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/362/976

Answer (score 6):

This is fully covered in the Help Center.  You'll note that on the closed question there is a notification:

> This question does not appear to be about science fiction or fantasy within the scope defined in the [help center](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Following the link in this notification (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) brings you to this list:

> **What topics can I ask about here?**
>
> Science Fiction & Fantasy Stack Exchange is for questions targeted towards science fiction and fantasy enthusiasts. This includes questions about:
>
> - Plot, character, or setting explanations
> - Historical or societal context of a work
> - Behind-the-scenes and fandom information
> - Story identification
> - Franchise/series reading or viewing order
>
> **What about other Science Fiction and Fantasy related questions?**
>
> Not all questions have a home on Stack Exchange. Please note the following types of questions are off-topic here:
>
> - Facts easily found on a reference site: Who played X in Y?
> - Questions calling for a list of works, authors, ...: What are all the books that have X? Who wrote about topic Y?
> - Reading or viewing recommendations: I liked X, what should I watch next?
> - **Genre classification: Is X Science Fiction?**

The last answer in the "off-topic" list answers your specific question, and the entire quote answers your general question.

I note that you haven't got the "Informed" badge, which is automatically awarded for reading the Tour, so I'd suggest that you do so and also follow the links to the Help Center from there.

Comment: I notice that the "Facts easily found on a reference site: Who played X in Y?" has disappeared from the Help Centre

Answer (score 2):

As per Beofett's answer [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1083/are-questions-whose-answers-would-determine-if-a-work-could-be-categorized-as-sc/1085#1085), questions that ask if a specific work is SciFi is considered off-topic for the main site.

The canonical reference for the off-topicness is this answer: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/362/976

(and the whole thread it's on is a good answer for "what constitudes an offtopic Q")